# How to schedule an alarm so that the intent is broadcast everytime the date changes?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want to schedule an alarm which throws an intent when the *date changes*.

I know that this would do this the job

```
alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,triggerAtTime, interval,alarmIntent);
```

But what is confusing me is what to put in the triggerAtTime and the interval.It says  System.currentTimeMillis() timebase.

I might be installing the app on any day so the TriggerAtTime should be midnight of that day and the interval would be 24 hours from there on.

How can I acheive this.Can someone tell me what to put in TriggerAtTime and interval in the required format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They both are of type long and I think you need to set them in milliseconds...

Answer (score 0):

For the triggerAtTime, this is the time of the first hit of your alarm.

The interval param is the time betwen each hit, for you 24 hours, in milliseconds : 24*60*60*1000

For exemple if you want to start updating 10 seconds after, your code should be :

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000),24*60*60*1000, alarmIntent);
```

If you want to set the first hit to be at midnight, you should calculate the time betwen midnight and now in milliseconds.
I hope you understand my frenchy bad english.

Bast

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), (24*60*60*1000), mPendingIntent);
```